change value in inner map with stream
I have this kind of map  Map<String, Object>  , As you can see there is a inner map "token" and inside this map, there is inner map "tokeninfo":
{
  "id": "44f79d20f28a2ea505b1",
  "type": "ONE",
  "cardIssued": "AA",
  "token": {
    "token1": "dummy",
    "tokenInfo": {
      "aaa": "007"
    },
    "payment": {
      "name": "test",
      "paymentType": {
        "card": "ONE"
      },
      "paymentAcc": "123"
    },
  "isDelegated": false,
  "attemptId": "981631"
}

In addition, I have this method :
private static HashMap<String, Object> getReplace(Map<String, Object> message) {
    HashMap<String, Object> message = new HashMap<>(message);

    for (String mapKey : PARAMETERS_FOR_REPLACE) {
        message.computeIfPresent(mapKey,
                (key, value) -> REGEX_ANY_CHAR.matcher(String.valueOf(value)).replaceAll("$^%%$"));
    }
    return message;
} 

I need to replace the value of some keys, from the map and inner map. like :
cardIssued ( from the map)
token1 ( from the inner map of the token)
aaa from the inner map of token -> tokeninfo
the value can be in any inner map, not just on the token and tokeninfo
Is there a way to stream all the values to check if it is a map and then call the method and replace it?
final result should be :
    {
  "id": "44f79d20f28a2ea505b1",
  "type": "ONE",
  "cardIssued": "$^%%$",
  "token": {
    "token1": "$^%%$",
    "tokenInfo": {
      "aaa": "$^%%$"
    },
    "payment": {
      "name": "test",
      "paymentType": {
        "card": "ONE"
      },
      "paymentAcc": "123"
    },
  "isDelegated": false,
  "attemptId": "981631"
}

if I run this:
  Map<String, Object> newMessage = getReplace(messageMap.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> (Object) entry.getValue())));

The value will change only in the "top" map.
Is there a way to use stream and do it in all inner and inner "inner" maps?

This sounds like an XY Problem.  A Map<String,String> cannot hold a map of maps.  It must be a Map<String, Map> or Map<String, Object>. Unfortunately, a design like this is fraught with problems.   You would probably be better off creating a class to be the values of the map with an appropriate key or perhaps just a list to hold the class instances.

WARNING: I strongly recommend you not to do it
If you must you can use:
public class MapReplacer {
    public Map<String, Object> replace(Map<String, Object> input) {
        return input.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        (e) -> process(e.getKey(), e.getValue())
                ));
    }

    private Object process(String key, Object value) {
        return switch (value) {
            case String s -> processValue(key, s);
            case Map m -> replace(m);
            default -> throw new RuntimeException();
        };
    }

    private String processValue(String key, String s) {
        if (key.equals("key to replace")) {
            // Put your replacement logic here
            return "new value";
        } else {
            return s;
        }
    }
}

I suggest you to review your approach of data storage. Map of Object is unsafe. Suggest you to use custom classes for your data structures.
